# redux form component not reflecting store state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I created a very simple yes / no component mapped to true / false values with redux form. 
When clicking "No" the value is updated in the store, but the component does not update.
Only after clicking Yes first the component updates when clicking No.

What am I doing wrong here ? why is the state in the store not reflected in the component ?
Note that it's important for my use case that initially, no button is clicked.

sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/r06VKjB4K

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const buttonStyle = {
  width: '50px',
  display: 'inline-block',
  border: '1px solid green',
  margin: '5px',
  padding: '5px',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

const ButtonBar = ({ options, input }) =>
  <div style={{ display: 'block' }}>
    {options.map(x =>
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          input.onChange(x.value);
        }}
        style={{
          ...buttonStyle,
          ...{
            backgroundColor: input.value === x.value ? x.selected : 'white',
          },
        }}
      >
        {x.displayName}
      </div>,
    )}
  </div>;

const SimpleForm = props => {
  return (
    <form>
      <div style={{ display: 'inline-block', border: '1px solid grey' }}>
        <Field
          name="myButton"
          component={ButtonBar}
          options={[
            {
              value: true,
              displayName: 'Yes',
              selected: 'green',
            },
            {
              value: false,
              displayName: 'No',
              selected: 'red',
            },
          ]}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'simple', // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm);
```

Comment: Can you not keep it like this
input.value == x.value
?

Comment: @VivekN No, I pointed out in my question why not

Comment: Indeed it is related with the `true/false` values.. If you replace them by `a` and `b` it works as expected. I'm not very familiar with redux-form but the docs might explain that.

Comment: because the false value and on click of No again the value is turning out to be false like how it was initially being an empty string which I am assuming redux-form treats as false.Since the state did not change which is why no re render.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer instead of values as true or false, can you keep them as something like Yes or No

Comment: @VivekN That's not an acceptable solution.

Comment: Please submit an issue linking to this sandbox.

Comment: @ErikR. https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that somewhere in the redux-form code, it treats the empty string and false as the same thing initially and does not trigger a rerender. It looks like redux-form uses this deepEquals function customizer:

```
const customizer = (obj, other) => {
  if (obj === other) return true
  if (
    (obj == null || obj === '' || obj === false) &&
    (other == null || other === '' || other === false)
  )
    return true

  if (obj && other && obj._error !== other._error) return false
  if (obj && other && obj._warning !== other._warning) return false
}
```

You could try setting the initial value to false yourself to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Accepting this answer because this does actually point directly to the code causing the bug in redux-form 6. It is going to be fixed in redux-form 7 ( hopefully -> https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/pull/3081)

Answer (score 3):

IDK exactly how redux-form works but you are having some issues regarding undefined initial state and false values; 
Using `format` you can handle that

https://codesandbox.io/s/BL50OzNZY

```
     format={(value) => value}
```

Just returns the value, no additional checks necessary.

Comment: That's very curious, since your function literally doesn't do anything. 
It seems like the action of adding a formatter itself has a side effect of fixing the problem.

Comment: That's right.. THere's no need for that IF, just returning the value itself overrides some other verification that excludes your falsy value..

Comment: well it works but now everyone using my component will need to include a mystery formatter that doesn't do anything. Not a pleasant solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because your Field "myButton" has initial state equal to "" and when you click on the "No" button the state changes to false but since the new state equals to the previous one("" == false) the component does not re-render.

You can fix this issue passing some initial state for your component which is different from you options(true and false). For example you can set the initial state as any string:

```
<SimpleForm
    initialValues={{ myButton: 'notTrueOrFalse' }}
    onSubmit={showResults}
  />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/0R1rw63nV

Comment: That initialized the store with `notTrueOrFalse`, which I believe, it's not ideal.

Comment: I appreciate that that works but it does not seem like a very good solution. 
In addition to initializing the form, upon submitting the form I'll have to add additional logic to remove that useless value. I just want to persist a boolean value.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer I believe you already need to add some additional logic because your component can give you three possible values: true, false, "". 
Maybe it makes sense to set initial value of the component as true or false by default.

Comment: The initial state of the component should be unselected. The value can  true, false or undefined, three distinct values yes. I'm also open to solutions where the third state is null or, worst case scenario, an empty string. But no other values.